# App for sending emails not installing on Galaxy Note 4 - Eclipse

Tags: android, email

I am trying to make an app from a tutorial homepage that teaches how to send an E-mail through an app. I am suffering many drawbacks and the LogCat is giving me some errors that I could not even have an idea on how to search for the problem. My code is: `

package com.example.email;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class EmailActivity extends Activity {

    private Button sendEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.email);

        sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email);
        sendEmail.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "blablabla@gmail.com" });
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey, how are you doing?");
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(emailIntent);
            }
        }));

    }



    }

`
```

and my logcat is represented here: http://pastebin.com/JKdVxQia

The manifest is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.email"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
        <activity
            android:name=".EmailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think that maybe my problem is with something related to libraries because I had problems with other projects.

Any help would be really appreciated I am stuck on this for the whole day looking on Google and StackOverflow.

Something also weird is why there is the word Facebook in the LogCat since I didn't make anything related to Facebook on the app.

Comment: If it's not installing, then it's probably something wrong with the manifest.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: You also need to show your manifest.

Comment: I will add them now.

Comment: @laalto I just added the manifest

Comment: @Simon the stack trace is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"` is misplaced. If you want to declare that your app requires the `INTERNET` permission itself, change it to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and place it inside the `manifest` element i.e. similar to `application`.

In the misplaced form, it declares that clients interacting with your app must have the `INTERNET` permission.

Also, the activity name in your manifest is `Email` while in code it is `EmailActivity`. Make sure the code and manifest agree on activity class names. You'd get an exception in logcat for this.

Comment: I made the change, cleaned and reopened eclipse. The problem persists.

Comment: I see you edited the activity name. Did you also remove the permission requirement from `application`?